# Why directive is not calling my controller method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Directive is not calling my controller method. Following is my code:

Controller:

```
    exports.controller = ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.addParamter = function () {
            console.log("here");
        };

       $scope.editParamter = function (item) {
            console.log(item);
       };
   }];
```

Page:

```
<formula-editor
    add-paramter="addParameter()"
    edit-paramter="editParameter(item)">
</formula-editor>
```

Directive:

Js:

```
exports.inject = function(app) {
    app.directive('formulaEditor', exports.directive);
    return exports.directive;
};

exports.directive = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/dist/views/formula-editor.html',
        scope: {
            addParameter: '&',
            editParameter: '&'
        }
    };
};
```

formula-editor.html:

```
<button ng-click="addParameter()"></button>
```

Comment: Show us the usage of controller, where do you reference it?

Comment: Fix your typo's in the html: `add-parameter` and `edit-parameter`

Answer (score 1):

Oh yea welcome to Angular ! You made a boo boo here your  `$scope.addParamter()` function name is wrong (misspelled) in your HTML,so your directive is not able to find the mentioned  `addParameter()` function in directive tag.So just change your main html like below

From

```
<formula-editor
    add-paramter="addParameter()"
    edit-paramter="editParameter(item)">
</formula-editor>
```

To

```
<formula-editor
    add-paramter="addParamter()"
    edit-paramter="editParamter(item)">
</formula-editor>
```

Here is a working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PhyQIt5nbJ9kUc6GZ3Mj?p=preview) of your directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.It might work for u.

```
exports.directive = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/dist/views/formula-editor.html',
        scope: {
            addParameter: '&addParamter',
            editParameter: '&editParamter'
        }
    };
};
```

Instead of

```
<formula-editor
    add-paramter="addParameter()"
    edit-paramter="editParameter(item)">
</formula-editor>
```

you can use

```
<formula-editor
    addParamter="addParameter()"
    editParamter="editParameter(item)">
</formula-editor>
```

This would be better.